# same record in two inherited postgres tables

Tags: postgresql, inheritance

I've got an old system that uses postgres table inheritance and I don't know much about it, but I have this situation:

there's three tables:
"person", "student" and "teacher"

both "student" and "teacher" inherit from "person".

Now, I have a student who became a teacher and I need to save him in both tables. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You will have three inserts, one for eache table you want.

```
insert into person ...
insert into student ...
insert into teacher ...
```

more information in http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/ddl-inherit.html

Comment: Thanks, this wasn't working at first because I tried to suppress the repeated data.